# Wordpress wp_remote_post

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to use wp_remote_post to send information from one server to my other website.

So basically, I have added this line to my code -

```
$sidebarHTTP = site_url(); // Retrieves HTTP Url of sidebar
$sidebarActivation = $sidebar.' , '.$sidebarHTTP; // Activate Sidebar 
$args = array(
  'method' => 'post',
  'body' => array('sidebar' => $sidebar, 'sidebarHTTP' => $sidebarHTTP),
  'user-agent' => 'My site'
);
wp_remote_post( 'http://mysite.com', $args ); // Loads all default data
```

So basically, it doesn't send anything. Yes, I have correct domain entered. Maybe it does send something, but I don't know how can I retrieve the $args['body'] from that site. Also, I tried adding $response = wp_remote_post.... and then sending mail $response['body'], but it just sends source code of homepage to email.

Would appreciate help.

Comment: 1st, Do U see this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_post; 2nd, Do U check curl is turned on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to enable cURL in your php.ini file.

`wp_remote_post()` uses a class called `WP_Http` that in turn can use one of three transport classes (see file `class-http.php` function `_get_first_available_transport`).

POST method will work with class `WP_Http_Curl`, but will not work with class `WP_Http_Streams` (the cURL fallback).

The alternative is to use `wp_remote_get()`