# How to receive data on other server with wp_remote_post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So basically, I'm posting data with wp_remote_post, and I want to receive sent data (username and password) on other server. How would I do that? I tried `<?php echo $_POST['username']; ?>` (nothing else before or nothing else after), but it didn't work. Can't find it either in Wordpress Codex.

Comment: Is this the same type of question as [#11096611](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096611/wordpress-wp-remote-post)?  Possible resolve submitted there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress protects you from so it's harded to exploit your code.

Use this code to make it work:

in functions.php add:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_my_var');
function add_my_var($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = 'username';
    return $public_query_vars;
}
```

and then you can use in your code to read the variable:

```
get_query_var('username');
```

This thread helped: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-an-extra-parameter-in-an-url

Comment: Hello, what I must insert in $args place? do I need to insert the $_POST['username'] inside there?

Comment: I've updated the answer with example. I can't try it now but it should work.

Comment: Hello, well baiscally I sovled out problem by removing 'method' => 'post' from sending script, but I'll accept yoru answer ;)!

Comment: This may be the same as [#11096611](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096611/wordpress-wp-remote-post)